# OS X server VPN local ip

Tags: vpn, mac-osx-server

I have 10.6.2 server on the internet.  I want to vpn into it to get access.  I start VPN and it gives me an address in the range I have set 192.168.2.100-192.168.2.105.

However the server itself does not have a local ip of 192.168.2.x so I cannot ping it or ssh into it or anything.

The machine VPNing gets an ifconfig entry that looks like this:

```
ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
 inet 192.168.2.100 --> 70.72.xxx.xxx netmask 0xffffff00
```

Where I think it should get:

```
ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
 inet 192.168.2.100 --> 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00
```

I can't find anywhere to set the local vpn IP address.  And I can't find a pptpd.conf file either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some questions: How do you connect your server to the internet? What is it's real IP address? Do you use Server Admin to configure the internal VPN server?

Comment: I use server admin to create the L2TP server. The server is connected directly to the internet on a public IP.

Answer (score 0):

I 'solved' this by using ssh tunnels instead.  Picked up [Meerkat](http://codesorcery.net/meerkat) to help create the tunnels and advertise services via Bonjour.

Never figured out what was wrong with the VPN.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> Where I think it should get: inet 192.168.2.100 --> 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00

Nope. Point-to-point connections don't need this. It can be 1.2.3.4 to 4.3.2.1 easily.

Comment: Every other VPN I have used gives me an address that shares the values covered by netmask.  Without it, it seems that I cannot move data through the server.  ie when setting 'Send all traffic over VPN connection', I am unable to do DNS queries.  I am running a local DNS server on the server and it does pass the DNS entries along.

Comment: A fact that you never seen a thing doesn't mean it couldn't have happened sometimes. :-)